# Generate a data set with set means and variances based on Color

Tags: r, data-generation

I have a this dataset `structure(list(Color = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("blue", "green", "red"
), class = "factor")), .Names = "Color", row.names = c(NA, -30L
), class = "data.frame")`

I would like to add a column that assigns a mean of 5 and a variance of 2 to blue, a mean of 10 and variance of 4 to green, and mean of 100 and variance of 15 to red..

Comment: Does the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is sorted as in the example, create vectors for the means and std.deviations. Then use `Map` to call `rnorm` on each group:

```
mus <- c(5, 10, 100)
sds <- c(2, 4, 15)
nums <- Map(function(n,mu, sd) rnorm(n, mu, sd), table(df1$Color), mus, sds)
df1$rndm <- unlist(nums)
df1
# Color       rndm
# 1   blue   5.048143
# 2   blue   8.159234
# 3   blue   7.029401
# 4   blue   3.298584
# 5   blue   3.388559
# 6   blue   3.125807
# 7   blue   3.428520
# 8   blue   3.659469
# 9   blue   7.881609
# 10  blue   3.483098
# 11 green   5.942954
# 12 green   3.172638
# 13 green  10.872443
```

**update**

To replace without having to sort change the last line to:

```
df1[order(df1$Color),"rndm"] <- unlist(nums)
```

Comment: My data is not sorted.. is there a way to do this by specific color..?  I should be able to sort it otherwise.. just curious.

Comment: You can add `stack(nums)` it will sort for you bc the list has names

Comment: Another way was added.